# Как организовать бизнес логику в asp.net mvc + entity framework?

Tags: asp.net, ооп, entity-framework, .net

Всем привет! В книге Фаулера "Архитектура корпоративных програмных приложений" описаны три способа представления бизнес логики: Сценарий транзакции (Transaction Script), Модель предметной области (Domain Model) и Модуль таблицы (Table Module), в дальнейшем именую их, как СТ, МПО и МТ сооветственно. Так как СТ меня не интересует и врядли часто используется с asp.net mvc, я буду говорить только о МПО и МТ.

Представим такую архитектуру:

Контроллер - занимается исключительно роутингом и всем что связано с представленим, о получении данных он ничего не знает.

Модель - несколько классов которые не имеют точного соответствия ни с контроллерами, ни с сущностями БД. Делает однообразную работу, в основном получение через репозитории необходимых данных, без сложной логики.

Репозитории - простые операции запросов к Entity Framework. Один репозиторий, одна сущность Entity Framework.

Entity Framework - простые сгенерированные по БД сущности.

В основном много однообразной работы, но иногда при возникновении сложной логики код становится ужасным.

Так вот, как можно назвать архитектуру такого приложения МПО или МТ? С одной стороны здесь ничего общего с МПО, ведь никаких архитектурных изощрений нет, но по идее с МТ тоже мало общего. Цитата с книги - "Основное отличие модуля таблицы от модели предметной
области состоит в том, что если, например, приложение обслуживает множество заказов, в соответствии с моделью предметной области придется сконструировать по одному
объекту на каждый заказ, а при использовании модуля таблицы понадобится всего один
объект, представляющий одновременно все заказы.". А как мы знаем при использовании Entity Framework придется сконструировать по одному объекту на каждый заказ.

Как это все понимать, это основанная на EF мутация обоих видов? Также помнится, что в той книге автор писал, что присутствие EF в платформе .net побуждает писать в стиле МТ, но лучше писать с МПО, так как такая система легко расширяется. Я так и не понимаю, как это должно быть устроено? И как выглядят настоящие ООП приложения с использованием EF?

Ну кажется это все, надеюсь на ответы. Спасибо!

Продолжение размышлений в сторону роли контроллера в такой архитектуре ищите [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/223775/%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD-%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%80-%D0%B2-asp-net-mvc)

Comment: В общем то, у меня контроллер достаточно тонкий. Он занимается перенаправлениями валидацией и отправкой результата(иногда с небольшим преобразованием). Бизнес логики там точно не присутствует. Все же спасибо, за интерес к вопросу. Похоже, что больше никто ничего не ответит. Грустно:(

Comment: jojo97: Вопрос и правда непростой и достаточно специфичный, я не уверен, что многим попадалась такая архитектура. Мне, например, не попадалась.

Comment: В этом то и дело, что никто не видел реализации МПО в ASP.NET, а если кто и видел, то не хочет рассказывать:)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*(Это не совсем ответ на вопрос, скорее, некоторый поток мыслей, который, возможно, окажется вам полезным)*

- В архитектуре, которую "нужно представить", есть изъян — использование [`skinny models.`](http://www.slideshare.net/damiansromek/thin-controllers-fat-models-proper-code-structure-for-mvc)

> Модель не должна заниматься перекладывание объектов из пустого в порожнее, а должна быть близка к `problem domain` и должна содержать `domain-specific` логику. Все проверки, конвертации сущностей, [вообще все, что можно вынести из контроллера без нарушения принципов MVC, должно быть в модели.](http://goo.gl/J33kQ)

- Довольно странным выглядит упоминание репозиториев и `Entity Framework` при разговоре об архитектуре.

> - Это — детали реализации интерфейса модели, которые к архитектуре имею довольно посредственное отношение. Хорошо спроектированном интерфейс модели должен допускать подмену `Entity Framework` на произольный `ORM` или, например, на `stub` реализацию, которая читает данные из `.txt` файла.
> - То есть, если мы уж говорим об `MVC,` то репозитории и `EF` напрямую с ним не связаны. А значит дизайн `layer'a` с `Entity Framework` **нужно рассматривать отдельно.**

- На эту тему могу посоветовать [избавиться от такой сущности как репозиторий,](http://goo.gl/PraDg) поскольку она, скорее всего, является лишним `abstraction layer,` вводит ненужную сложность и неявно приводит к написанию слишком обобщенного кода`:`

> *"Ой, а чтобы протащить такой запрос к сущностям придется модифицировать `Repository<T>`. Надо написать тесты. Ой, а для этого `use case` такой метод в `Repository<T>` работать не будет. Ой, а какой бы `workaround` тут придумать...".*

- См. также [**Entity Framework 4.0 Recipes: A Problem-Solution Approach.**](http://goo.gl/wvZS2)

Comment: В моем понимании репозиторий это класс в котором есть методы со всеми необходимыми модели запросами, то есть не набросок с CRUD операциями, а полноценный класс со всеми нужными запросами. Уточните, что вы имеете ввиду?

Comment: @jojo97

- В тексте вопроса вы написали *"простые операции запросов,"* что лично у меня вызвало ассоциацию именно с `CRUD.` Тем не менее, даже в когда в классе `Repository` запросы не-`CRUD,` а какие специфичные для задачи, лучшим вариантом мне кажется инкапсулировать эту логику в модели и не вводить лишний уровень абстракции.

- В противном случае у вас получаются классы `Model` и `Repository,` которые совершенно непонятным образом должны делить ответственность (или вообще получится модель-роутер, которая просто переадресовывает вызовы классу `Repository,` что тоже кажется бессмысленным).

Comment: "лучшим вариантом мне кажется инкапсулировать эту логику в модели и не вводить лишний уровень абстракции." и "Хорошо спроектированном интерфейс модели должен допускать подмену Entity Framework на произольный ORM или, например, на stub реализацию, которая читает данные из .txt файла." - это не противоречит друг другу?

Comment: @jojo97 Нет. У вас есть интерфейс модели и ее конкретная реализация. В вашем примере вы могли бы, например, сделать интерфейс `IModel` и конкретную реализацию `EntityFrameworkModel,` в которой (что соответствует названию) инкапсулирована вся логика взаимодействия с `Entity Framework.`

Comment: Ок, понял. У меня уже сформировалось некоторое представление об этом всем, оставайтесь на линии, так как нужна будет критика, после того как я напишу об этом.

Answer (score 0):

Вот как я понимаю, должна быть реализована МПО.

DB First EF - Простые объекты без методов.

Модель - обертки для объектов EF содержащие методы с логикой например для пользователя: List<User> ListMutualFriends() или List<Photos> ListPhotosWithGoodRaiting(), или void ChangePassword(string password). Конструкторы таких объектов принимают либо сам объект EF либо какие то идентифицирующие данные например id и получают из EF необходимую сущность. Репозитории выбрасываем или делаем что-то типа глобального репозитория CRUD, чтобы немного разгрузить обертки, и пишем запросы напрямую из этих оберток. Также в обертках все внешние методы должны возвращать сущности EF, иными словами, в вид попадают EF сущности без методов или производные сущности, которые не имеют прямого отображения в БД и являются классами из модели, но также представляют только данные без методов.

Контроллер - тут я не уверен, стоит ли напрямую обращаться к этим оберткам из контроллера или сделать очень тонкую прослойку. С одной стороны, минимальная опасность толстого контроллера, с другой стороны, бесполезная прослойка, ведь я попытаюсь инкапсулировать всю логику в обертках.

В общем, прошу всех высказать свое мнение. Надеюсь, что в этой архитектуре есть немного здравого смысла.