# Что должен делать тонкий контроллер в asp.net mvc?

Tags: asp.net, controller, mvc

Всем привет! Что должен делать правильный тонкий контроллер в ASP.NET MVC?

Вообще контроллер может делать все что угодно, но я бы выделил среди его обязанностей следующее:

1. Получать и, возможно, проверять на правильность данные от пользователя.
2. Получать данные из модели и передавать их в вид.
3. Возможно как-то изменять эти данные для отображения.
4. Делать редиректы или выводить ошибки, если так сказала модель.
5. Добавлять кукисы и проверять права пользователя.

Есть проблемки со третьим и четвертым пунктами.

1. Может ли контроллер модифицировать данные или вся работа с данными должна происходить в модели, и если может то в каких случаях?
2. Представим ситуацию, нужно вывести друзей пользователя, по айди пользователя.  Контроллер передает id и получает List, а в случае если пользователя по id не найдено, модель должна сообщить об этом контроллер. Получается что-то такое:

   ```
   public ActionResult ListUserFriends(int userId) {

       bool userExists;
       var friends = UsersModel.ListUserFriends(userId, out userExists);
       if(!userExists) {
           return View("Error");
       }
       return View(friends);
   }
   ```

Это как мы видим не очень удобно. Удобнее было бы принимать решения о редиректах в модели, а тогда смысл от контроллера? Или возможно сделать контроллер потолще? Если принять такой подход, к которому я пришел [в этом вопросе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/223555/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B3%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%81-%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%BA%D1%83-%D0%B2-asp-net-mvc-entity-framework?%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0=1&focusedAnswerId=223708#223708). Здесь благодаря шаблону бизнес логики Domain Model, большинство логики перешло в обертки сущностей и на долю модели или толстого контроллера выпадает только управление этими обертками. В общем жду каких либо советов.

Comment: а теперь представьте, что вы хотите вызвать метод модели в другом месте, а вывод в другом формате (например, вывод в xml-формате или rss ленту) и вопросы такого рода будут отпадать самостоятельно

Comment: @Сергей Ваше замечание вполне разумное и сгодилось бы в качестве комментария — но ответа на вопрос оно не содержит, так что публиковать его как ответ не стоило.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Думаю, вряд ли для кого-то окажется сюрпризом, что контроллер (в том числе и в ASP.NET  MVC) должен сводить к минимуму те или иные манипуляции, направленные на реализацию бизнес-логики. То есть первые два пункта вашего списка можно считать верными. А вот что касается изменения данных для отображения - а, простите, зачем? Модель готовит данные таким образом, чтобы представление их могло отобразить без каких-либо дополнительных действий как со своей стороны, так и со стороны контроллера. Важное уточнение - тут я говорю именно о модели, а не о каких-либо сущностях, скажем, моделирующих таблицы базы данных, которые моделями как таковыми не являются. Что касается добавления кукисов - ну это уж вовсе частное, которое не нужно смешивать с общими принципами. По поводу проверок прав пользователя - для этого, вероятно, имеет смысл создать отдельную сущность, которая будет этим заниматься, а не забивать подобными задачами контроллер. По поводу редиректов - в приведенном вами примере нет какой-то неимоверной логики, лдя которой стоило бы выделять отдельные модели, и логика наподобие

```
return была_ошибка ? View("Error") : View("Что-то там");
```

в контроллере предосудительной не является. Другое дело, если подобные редиректы имеют более сложную внутреннюю логику, тогда да, загромождать ими контроллер тоже ни к  чему.

> Удобнее было бы принимать решения о редиректах в модели

не удобнее. Модель - это некая сущность, моделирующая что-то из бизнес-логики. Знать что-либо о каких бы то ни было редиректах, представлениях и страницах она не должна.

Напоследок пару слов не помню откуда:

> Начинающие программисты (особенно в веб-программировании, где аббревиатура MVC стала популярна) очень часто трактуют архитектурную модель MVC как пассивную модель MVC. В этом случае модель выступает исключительно совокупностью функций для доступа к данным, а контроллер содержит бизнес-логику. В результате код моделей по факту является средством получения данных из СУБД, а контроллер представляет собой типичный модуль, наполненный бизнес-логикой, или скрипт в терминологии веб-программирования. В результате такого понимания MVC разработчики стали писать код, который Pádraic Brady, известный в кругах сообщества Zend Framework, охарактеризовал как ТТУК — «Толстые тупые уродливые контроллеры» (Fat Stupid Ugly Controllers)

Comment: Другое дело, если подобные редиректы имеют более сложную внутреннюю логику, тогда да, загромождать ими контроллер тоже ни к чему.

В таком случае, где должны приниматься эти решения и как?

Comment: в таком случае пишите отдельный класс (отдельную модель) и обращайтесь к нему в контроллере, точно также как вы обращаетесь в контроллере к другим моделям

Answer (score 1):

> Может ли контроллер модифицировать данные или вся работа с данными должна происходить в модели, и если может то в каких случаях?

На мой взгляд может, если модель является лишь представлением данных из БД с использованием типов языка.

На текущий момент, например, есть проект на MVC4, в нём модель - лишь каркас данных и минимум проверок (в основном ограничения длины текста, проверка на отрицательные значения ну и по мелочам). Вся логика же лежит на контроллере и сервисах (сервисы на WCF рулят загрузкой/выгрузкой данных).

> Представим ситуацию, нужно вывести друзей пользователя, по айди пользователя. Контроллер передает id и получает List<User>, а в случае если пользователя по id не найдено, модель должна сообщить об этом контроллер. Получается что-то такое:

Честно говоря, ничего предосудительного не вижу в таком подходе. Контроллер отвечает в данном случае ещё и за то, чтобы во View не попало непонятно что. Допустим, пустая коллекция из пользователей просто напросто свалила бы View. Модели знать про то, что должно уйти в итоге в представление, а что нет вообще не нужно.

Попытки вынести лишнюю логику в модель приведёт к тому, что модель будет знать что-то о представлении, а это допустимо только для контроллера.

Comment: А если предположить что большинство логики будет скрыто в обертках сущностей, как я описал в том вопросе, нужно ли делать отдельный слой отделяющий модель от контроллера или можно в контроллере управлять этими обертками?